# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Tags: java

I'm using JDK 1.5 in my web project and using maven for compile.

I was facing this:

```
WebServiceException ("javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found")
```

in my project. To fix that I used two approaches:

- First, I add jaxws-rt-2.1.4 in my class path.(Also made entry in POM.xml)
- Second, Added jar in jre/lib folder

But after this I am facing this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
```

Does anyone have any idea that could help me?

Comment: you need to add [jaxb-impl](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.6/) jar to your classpath

Answer (score 3):

Adding a dependency on [jaxb-impl](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.xml.bind%7Cjaxb-impl%7C2.2.6%7Cjar) should be sufficient, as this transitively depends on jaxb-api, which is the JAR containing the class it's complaining about.  In Java 6, `javax.xml.bind` is part of the JRE by default so it would work out of the box there.

Answer (score 1):

add this dependency to pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy, I followed the same but it not work's at my end:(